# Negative number printed after division with XC8 C compiler

Tags: c, pic, xc8

These lines of code:

```
long duration;
duration = (long)(500*g_sampleTimeInSeconds) / 60;
printf("Memory will fill up after %d minutes\n", duration);
```

are producing a negative number when g_sampleTimeInSeconds is greater than 65. When g_sampleTimeInSeconds = 65 the printed number is 541 but when it is 66 the printed number is -542 rather then the correct number of 550. This is also the case when g_sampleTimeInSeconds is replaced with hardcoded values.

This code is compiled with the XC8 compiler to run on Microchip PICs

UPDATE:

g_sampleTimeInSeconds is an 16 bit int

Comment: Please show the data type for g_sampleTimeInSecond

Comment: Change to `(500L*g_sampleTimeInSeconds) / 60;`

Comment: @chux your method also works - it seems only one of the multiplication  operands needs to be cast to a long for this to work

Comment: Note: Should add `l`: `printf("Memory will fill up after %ld minutes\n", duration);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this a 16-bit compiler?  My guess is that this is a integer conversion issue. where you are exceeding the size of a 16 bit integer, which is being treated as a two's complement number.

So, in your example, you are casting the results of the calculation to a long, **after** the calculation takes place.  Assuming that g_sampleTimeInSeconds is a signed 16-bit int, then

500*66 = 33000, which is larger than the largest positive value of 32767 allowed for a signed 16 bit number.  This causes an overflow, and the intermediate value is calculated as 33000 - 65536 = -32536. -32536/60 = -542.xxx.

So, you need to either cast the values within the expression, or change the data type of g_sampleTimeInSeconds to a long.

Comment: Here's all the [boring math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) behind it for those interested.

Comment: I'm not in front of the hardware right now so can't test but this makes perfect sense. I didn't realise that the type of g_sampleTimeInSeconds would affect the rest of the calculation like that. I'll accept once fully tested